# PHP Array key strings without quotation marks

Tags: php, superglobals

I am moving the files to the server and is using variables like $_GET[mode] without ''(single quotes)  in 'mode'. It works perfectly locally but on the server i am getting notices.. How can i overcome this?here is my phpinfo file
[phpinfo](http://solutiq.com/phpinfo.php)
Is there any way we can have same behavior to work on server as well?

Comment: Use single quotes. It doesn't work "perfectly", you just ignore PHP when it's telling you "hey, you shouldn't be doing this!".

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It is bad practice and causes issues like you have seen...

Comment: i know i can use E_NOTICE but i donot want to use that ...it would be alot of trouble to move everything

Comment: Also can i use variables like $_LANG in php?

Comment: @June: Come on. One question at a time.

Comment: @June It may be a lot of trouble but your existing code is incorrect. Either you fix the problems, or you get error messages. Your choice. And yes, you can name use/name variables like `$_LANG` or whatever you choose, but a) this is not recommended in case a future version PHP decides to define those variables and it may break you code, and b) they will not be superglobals - (annoyingly) there is no way to define a custom superglobal in PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How can you overcome the `E_NOTICE`s that complain that you forgot quotes around your strings?

Add quotes around your strings.

```
$_GET['mode']
```

---

Also it sounds like the `error_reporting` level on your local server is *not sufficient*. It should be high, so that you *see* these sorts of mistakes as you develop your website/application.

On your production server it may be set lower.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the [PHP Manual on Arrays:](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

> **Why is $foo[bar] wrong?**
>
> Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, `$foo['bar']` is correct, while `$foo[bar]` is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts:

```
<?php
$foo[bar] = 'enemy';
echo $foo[bar];
// etc
?>
```

> This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an undefined constant (`bar`) rather than a string (`'bar'` - notice the quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named `bar`, then PHP will substitute in the string `'bar'` and use that.

So, in other words: `mode` is an undefined constant.

Quoting the [PHP Manual on Constants](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php):

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a string (CONSTANT vs "CONSTANT"). An [error of level `E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php) will be issued when this happens. See also the manual entry on [why `$foo[bar]` is wrong](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar) (unless you first [`define()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) bar as a constant). If you simply want to check if a constant is set, use the [`defined()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) function.

**Solution: put quotes around the key.**

Comment: `mode` _is_ an undefined constant. :)